# Which type of join to use in R, tidyverse preferably

Tags: r, tidyverse

I think the answer to this is staring me right in the face in the documentation, but maybe I'm just having a brain fart, i can't figure it out.

Lets say I have two tables of patients, table a and table b.

I know there is some overlap of the same patients in both tables, and their medical record is what I would join on.

I want to get all the new patients from B I might not have, and add them to my preexisting table A.  I only want to be left with the columns from A, and I don't need any of the new columns from B.  There may be columns that overlap between the two and if they merge on this that's great too, but medical record number is the important one.  What type of join would you use?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps `semi_join`

Comment: @akrun Just tried semi_join, worked correctly in the sense it kept only the columns from table A, but it removed patients it couldn't find in B.  So A now has less.   I want A to get all the new patients from B, so A would grow.  If that makes sense?

Comment: In that case, mmay be `full_join`

Comment: @akrun Just tried full_join, that brought in all the new columns from B I didn't need, (though it did get the patients).  I guess I could remove those columns, but its like 300 new columns..

Comment: I would subset the columns of interest that are needed for the join in B.  `B[c(1, 3, 5, 10)]` and then use `full_join`

Comment: ´left_join(a,b)´ should give you what you want?

Comment: @OweJessen left_join seems to give me all the columns from both

Comment: @JoeCrozier you can adjust by using `left_join(a, b %>% select(...))`

Comment: @OweJessen yea I just didn't want to have to because i need like 30 columns and to drop like 200 columns.  I may have to, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a **full join** (you need full to get the entries from both tables, a left will only get you entries from the left table) and select the columns from your left dataframe using  the `colnames` function so you don't have to do a bunch of typing. Assuming your medical record has the same name in both dataframes.

```
library(dplyr)

left = data.frame('medical_record' = 1:3, 'col_1' = 4:6, 'col_2' = 7:9)
right = data.frame('medical_record' = 3:5, 'col_3' = 3:5, 'col_4' = 1:3)

joined = left %>% 
  full_join(right) %>% 
  select(colnames(left))
head(left)
head(right)
head(joined)
```

Output:

```
> head(left)
  medical_record col_1 col_2
1              1     4     7
2              2     5     8
3              3     6     9
> head(right)
  medical_record col_3 col_4
1              3     3     1
2              4     4     2
3              5     5     3
> head(joined)
  medical_record col_1 col_2
1              1     4     7
2              2     5     8
3              3     6     9
4              4    NA    NA
5              5    NA    NA
```